# CSS attribute selector in IE7 Standards mode

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

To make a long story short: I need to override display:none!important on some elements that have display:inline set inline on the HTML element itself.

This needs to work in IE with IE7 standards mode set.

Have a look at my pastebin link for details: http://pastebin.com/m06YXwHq
Result: http://cdpn.io/sgrjz

This works in IE9 with IE9 Standards Mode (and all other modern browsers too), but no with IE7 Standards Mode.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: this question does a good job of illustrating why `!important` is considered such bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I AM aware of the issues. I'm not in complete control over the code, so that's why I'm in this mess.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly can't see a way to do what you want in pure CSS, other than fixing up your code to remove the mountains of bad practice that have led you down this path in the first place.

As you presumably already know, IE7 does not support attribute selectors used in this way so you're scuppered on that front, and the only other viable solution is to add a class to the element and style that (but if you could do that, I imagine you'd already have done it).

Beyond that, you're looking at Javascript solutions.

You could try one of the polyfill scripts that add support for newer CSS features to old IE. Either [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). These two scripts are generally pretty good at adding support for CSS selectors to old IE, but what you're doing here is a real edge-case, and I would not be surprised at all if they didn't cope with it. Give them a try by all means, but don't expect miracles.

Given that, a more manual approach might work better: If you're using jQuery or a similar library, they should be able to select the required elements pretty easily, and you could work from there. (if you're not using jQuery or a library with a built-in selector engine then you'll struggle, but if you're supporting IE7 it would be a surprise to hear you're not using jQuery already)

But the real message that comes out of this is that inline styles and the CSS `!important` modifier are bad practices and will come back to bite you. And you've been bitten pretty hard.

Comment: Actually, IE7 HAVE support for attribute selectors. But apparently you can't use the style-attribute.. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector

Comment: My understanding was that it isn't supported at all in IE7, but it's been a while since I even tried to use it in IE7, so I may be wrong. In any case, we agree that the specific case you need it for doesn't work, so it doesn't make any difference to the outcome. (I would guess that it does make it even less likely that the polyfill libraries will help, though)

Comment: IE7 has support for CSS2/CSS3 attribute selectors, but it is incredibly patchy.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated, IE7 is unable to use the style-attribute as CSS selector.

I managed to work around it, so I'm out of the woods. No solution anyone else would find a use for as it's particular to my setup.

Thanks for all the input anyway!

/J

Comment: No harm letting us know what you did to solve it though? Otherwise you may as well not post an answer in the first place.

Comment: I posted the "solution" - my only lead was a dead end. I think that's reason enough.

But fine: I managed to use the hierarchy of my HTML page instead of using the style-attribute to achieve the same thing.